# Let StackExchange dialog pop up on hover as well

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

Since the change of the envelope/recent activity, which introduced a hover dialog behind the username on the top bar, I am so getting used to it that I unintentionally started to rant when the StackExchange dialog didn't do the same when I was about to view a new message in the inbox. I then realized that it has never behaved like that and I just have to give the mouse left button a press.

Can we have a hover popup for the StackExchange dialog as well? More consistent site behaviour yields a better user experience.

Comment: Related, as something of a half-superset to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83735/stylistic-and-functional-inconsistencies-between-multi-super-whatever-you-call-th

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that. Let me look.

Comment: I agree with him on most points, but I'm not sure if I have to delete the current question as a dupe. The other question is tagged as a discussion, not as a feature request and it covers so many points of which I put bigger question marks on some of them.

Comment: I'm not suggesting deletion or closure. The linked question just asks for consistency - either click or no click. You're specifically requesting no-click, which is difference enough. But while we speak of inconsistencies, it doesn't hurt to track related questions.

Comment: Yes, I understood :)

Answer (score 4):

Please don't... break the internets.  Things popping up on hover is quite annoying actually, because things happen just by randomly moving the mouse.  It is painful enough having the mouseover sometimes work and sometimes not over the username, but that is too late to fix - actually clicking already has an action attached to the click.  At times, I have to move away, click on the page elsewhere (set focus), then move back to get the hovery thing.

If I want something I'll initiate it with a click thank you!

`<unrelated>`
*There is this newspaper in this country that decided to implement a pop-over menu that came up whenever you hovered over the menu bar.  Okay that's not too bad, until you realize that the menu pop-over is 1/3 the screen height!  Innocuously moving the mouse = can't read news = bad*

`</unrelated>`