# Hover or click, take your pick

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Let StackExchange dialog pop up on hover as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85925/let-stackexchange-dialog-pop-up-on-hover-as-well)
> [Stylistic and functional inconsistencies between multi-super-whatever-you-call-them drop downs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83735/stylistic-and-functional-inconsistencies-between-multi-super-whatever-you-call-th)

User interface consistency means every 'action' should have the same 'effect'. There is nothing wrong with either hovering or clicking to achieve an effect **Edit** as long as the hover doesn't occupy more screen real-estate **End Edit**, but the interface should not mix both approaches:

[image: Hover or click]

As always, I have an opinion about which approach is right, and I'll explain why. I think SE should choose the 'click' approach as this positively is a user action. Sometimes, the mouse hovers over an element by accident and the user interface changes...

However, hover is very good when the hovering occupies the same screen real estate. For example, a graphical button that highlights when hovered over. That's great feedback to the user.

My 0,02€

**Edit** This is not an exact duplicate as my proposal is the exact opposite from the first question and the second question does not add any proposal. There is a subtle difference between hover, indifferent and click as recommendation.

**Final Edit** I see the reason for closing this question was changed. I think it could be merged, in a way, with:

> [Stylistic and functional inconsistencies between multi-super-whatever-you-call-them drop downs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83735/stylistic-and-functional-inconsistencies-between-multi-super-whatever-you-call-th)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let StackExchange dialog pop up on hover as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85925/let-stackexchange-dialog-pop-up-on-hover-as-well), [Stylistic and functional inconsistencies between multi-super-whatever-you-call-them drop downs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83735/stylistic-and-functional-inconsistencies-between-multi-super-whatever-you-call-th)

Comment: In response to your edit... The first part of your question says: **"There is nothing wrong with either hovering or clicking to achieve an effect, but the interface should not mix both approaches"** The first proposed duplicate suggests to make the behavior the same by changing the one odd behavior to conform with the two, rather than the more illogical change of the two similar behaviors to conform with the other odd variant.

Comment: And I don't see how this could be any more clearly an exact duplicate of the second proposed duplicate. That one even has a better explanation and presents a more coherent argument. Not to mention it was asked several months prior. It's not clear what you mean by "doesn't add any proposal". It certainly does. It proposes the same thing as you: make the behavior the same so the UI is more consistent.

Comment: I'm actually saying the 'click' is better than the 'hover'. The second question is clearly very well presented and I did +1. I wouldn't mind having the question merged, if that's a possibility, even though I'm not neutral.

Comment: The only advantage of merging is that it copies over the answers. This question doesn't have any answers, so there's little reason to merge it. Although posting this question has managed to get that one at least 5 or 6 more upvotes, so you've still accomplished something.