# Dropdowns binded to different events

Tags: support, user-interface

This is tiny question about current header dropdowns implementation. Just curious[image]

So, why is it so? Not a big deal, but really interesting.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83735/stylistic-and-functional-inconsistencies-between-multi-super-whatever-you-call-th http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85925/let-stackexchange-dialog-pop-up-on-hover-as-well